# Azure Resource Manager Authentication Failure

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to use node.js to access the azure resource manager with the following example code:

```html
msRestAzure.interactiveLogin(function(err, credentials) {
 if (err) console.log(err);
 var client = new resourceManagement.ResourceManagementClient(credentials, 'token');
 client.resources.list(function(err, result) {
   if (err) console.log(err);
   console.log(result);
 });
});
```

I get the following error when I run it:

```html
 { Error: The access token is from the wrong issuer 'https://sts.windows.net/token/'. It must match the tenant 'https://sts.windows.net/token/' associated with this subscription. Please use the authority (URL) 'https://login.windows.net/token' to get the token. Note, if the subscription is transferred to another tenant there is no impact to the services, but information about new tenant could take time to propagate (up to an hour). If you just transferred your subscription and see this error message, please try back later.
    at client.pipeline.error (D:\azure-arm\node_modules\azure-arm-resource\lib\resource\operations\resources.js:496:19)
    at retryCallback (D:\azure-arm\node_modules\ms-rest\lib\filters\systemErrorRetryPolicyFilter.js:89:9)
    at retryCallback (D:\azure-arm\node_modules\ms-rest\lib\filters\exponentialRetryPolicyFilter.js:140:9)
    at D:\azure-arm\node_modules\ms-rest\lib\filters\rpRegistrationFilter.js:59:14
    at handleRedirect (D:\azure-arm\node_modules\ms-rest\lib\filters\redirectFilter.js:39:9)
    at D:\azure-arm\node_modules\ms-rest\lib\filters\formDataFilter.js:23:14
    at Request.defaultRequest [as _callback] (D:\azure-arm\node_modules\ms-rest\lib\requestPipeline.js:125:16)
    at Request.self.callback (D:\azure-arm\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)


    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
```

Any place you see token, I've replaced the actual value that was there. The subscription ID I'm providing is correct. I have tried logging in directly rather than using the key above and it had the same effect. Ideally we'd want an application in azure to have access to the arm API but it doesn't look like that's possible in active directory, and I can't seem to get this to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have used ms-rest-azure versioned 2.6.0 and azure-arm-resource versioned 7.3.0 and it was working fine for me with the same code.

I think its secure to authenticate using service principal authentication way or basic authentication way rather than by interactive login authentication way. We have the steps of these other ways of authentication in here -> https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/Documentation/Authentication.md#using-authentication-in-your-nodejs-script which you may try if interested.

Also, as you are ideally looking for application in Azure to have access to the ARM API so I think its worthwhile to give a read of this article -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-api-authentication

Hope this helps!!